# Element type "myelement" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

My script function is defined inside a JSF2 form on a XHTML page and the following part of the code causes a problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('mycheckboxes');
   if(checkboxes.length > 0){
     for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
      var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
     }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When trying to access the page in FireFox 8 it prints the exception:

> Element type "checkboxes.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

what does this error mean?

Another question: is the script is executed before the pages is rendered? Because my checkboxes is loaded in the page during render phase of page (using JSF `<ui:repeat>`), so my guess is that I must make a condition to execute the code when the variable checkboxes is not null, am I right?

Comment: Scripts are executed when they are parsed so it's possible it is executes before the DOM elements exist.

Comment: Is your document XHTML or have you forgot to put your script into `<script>` tag?

Comment: That error looks like something is trying to interpret your JavaScript as HTML. What exactly is giving the error? The browser? Or a HTML validator? How is the JavaScript included - in a `script` element or a separate JavaScript file?

Comment: I don't know about JSF, but does your Javascript have the `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` things around? It seems to interpret `<checkboxes.length` as a tag.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the script? It sounds like an HTML error. Actually, it kind of sounds like it could be either... very strange.

Comment: I don't know about the error, unless you forgot to enclose your JS code in `<script>` tags, but as an aside your `if` statement is redundant since the `for` loop condition checks exactly the same thing.

Comment: question updated to cover comments.

Comment: Please ask individual questions in separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using XHTML and embedding scripts in the page.

XML doesn't have intrinsic CDATA sections, so `<` means "start of tag" even inside a script element.

If you were using real XHTML then you could represent it as `&lt;`, but then you couldn't serve the document as `text/html`.

Instead you can wrap the script content with an explicit CDATA section as [described in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) while also taking care to follow the relevant [text/html compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

You would probably be better off keeping your script in an external file and loading it with `<script src="..."></script>`.

For that matter, you are likely to be better off using HTML instead of writing XHTML and then jumping through hoops to make it work in browsers that expect HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you write this script directly in the JSF source - you have to escape symbols like `>`, `<`, `&` etc. with `&gt;`, `&amp;` ...

Another way is to use `CDATA` section:

```
<script language="javascript">//<![CDATA[

/* here your script */

//]]>
</script>
```

See also:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 1):

"This error comes from not closing an attribute tag".

http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2006/12/31/element-type-must-be-followed-by-either-attribute-specifications/